# openpyxl [Errno 13] permission denied when creating xlsx unless using debugger

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm trying to write an excel file using openpyxl. I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3, with Python 3.8.10.

When doing so, I get an exception

> Exception: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I should precise, the file is not already opened. When I'm running the same code with the debugger, the file is successfully written, no permission issues.
Anyone knows why it works with the debugger only? What can I do to make it work without it? I'm the admin of my machine so any lack of permission I can address. I just tried everything, nothing seems to cut it. I'm able to generate any other file extensions with the same code. For some reason just the xlsx causes issues.

I didn't post a code sample because it's definitely not the problem, but here goes:

```
wb = openpyxl.workbook.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = 'Title'
ws.append(["TITLE"])
wb.save(filename=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Example.xlsx"))
wb.close()
```

Comment: When you're using the debugger, does `os.getcwd()` have the same value as when you're not using it?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes same path

Comment: And you're sure that file is not already open inside Excel?

Comment: @JohnGordon 100%, otherwise even the debugger could not write it